# How to employ android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil with RxJava, LiveData and not generate Skipped ### frames

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

My current Android Application uses LiveData to populate my recyclerView.

Some users have 1000's of items to display.

I also allow my users to search/filter the items held in the recyclerView.

The initial display of the list is fine.

However when the user starts to search/filter the list from 1000's to 1 or 2 items the UX becomes very poor indeed with the UI becoming unresponsive for 10's of seconds.

My RecyclerView Adapter employs android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil to manage list item changes.

I have tried to employ RxJava in my activity onChange method to execute the diffing on a background thread

```
Observable.just(newItems)
        .doOnSubscribe(compositeDisposable::add)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .switchMap(new Function<List<ItemUI>, ObservableSource<DiffUtil.DiffResult>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<DiffUtil.DiffResult> apply(final List<ItemUI> itemUIs) {
                final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new GenericDiffUtilCallback<>(adapter.getCurrentItems(), newItems));

                return Observable.just(diffResult);
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<DiffUtil.DiffResult>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
                adapter.updateList(diffResult, articles);

            }
        });
```

My Adapter up[dateList method resembles this

```
public void updateList(final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult, final List<ItemUI> newItems) {

    this.items.clear();
    this.items.addAll(newItems);

    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

}
```

I am still seeing logcat messages such as this

```
Choreographer: Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

What mistake have I made to still be seeing skipped frames?

Is it possible to diff large list changes and still have a responsive UI?

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: @pskink does the paging library handle Diffing the displayed items? specifically when the number of displayed items is changing drastically e.g. between 0 - 5000, in milliseconds?

Comment: number of items loaded is more or less 10-30, not more, this is what paging is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted should, in theory, not execute the diff on the main thread.

Try the following:

```java
Observable.just(newItems)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())  // <------------------------------------
    .map(new Function<List<ItemUI>, DiffUtil.DiffResult>() {
        @Override
        public DiffUtil.DiffResult apply(final List<ItemUI> itemUIs) {
            return DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                new GenericDiffUtilCallback<>(
                    adapter.getCurrentItems(), itemUIs));
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(compositeDisposable::add) // <------------------------
    .subscribe(new Consumer<DiffUtil.DiffResult>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
            adapter.updateList(diffResult, articles);

        }
    });
```

You don't really need `switchMap`. Also if you really want that dispose to take effect, you have to move it down as much as possible, otherwise the position in the original question will have no effect on the diff computation below it.

I'd also check if you don't inadvertently run into threading issues such as the cases described in [this blog](https://medium.com/@jonfhancock/get-threading-right-with-diffutil-423378e126d2)

**Edit:**

If you have changing source, you can use `switchMap` but use `fromCallable` as well:

```
    .switchMap(itemUIs ->  {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new GenericDiffUtilCallback<>(
                adapter.getCurrentItems(), itemUIs))
        )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    })
```

Comment: @akamokd I thought I would need the switchMap as each time the user changes the search text I need to replace the current search with the next search term entered, otherwise I get contention on my adapters list of items

Comment: Okay, so you have something other than `just` actually. In that case yes, you need `switchMap` but also you need to make sure you don't block switchMap itself with the diff calculation. Put the diff inside a `fromCallable`.